# Count/Group By Then Left Join - Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I’m relatively new to SQL, so appreciate everyone’s help here!

I have two different tables in different schemas where I’m trying to do a count/group by and then a left join.

So I would be counting the number of records by “Country” in Table A where the "SNAP_DT" is = to a certain date and then doing a left join to get the “Regions” from Table B. So the end result would be the count of records by region.

Here’s what I’ve tried and it’s throwing an error (ORA-00923). Any ideas? Thanks!

```
SELECT A.WORK_ADDRESS_COUNTRY, COUNT(B.REGION) AS 'Region' 
FROM
   ODS.ODS_HEADCOUNT_DAILY A 
   LEFT JOIN
   (
   SELECT COUNTRY, REGION FROM ML.SANDBOX_ML
   ) B
   ON A.WORK_ADDRESS_COUNTRY = B.COUNTRY
WHERE SNAP_DT=TIMESTAMP '2021-03-14 00:00:00.000000'
AND EMPLOYEE_ID > '444444'
GROUP BY A.WORK_ADDRESS_COUNTRY
```

Comment: That error comes from the alias. It should be without quotes or in double quotes - AS Region OR AS "Region". Single quotes will give you this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, your query should look something like this:

```
    SELECT B.REGION as "Region", count(*) 
FROM
   ODS.ODS_HEADCOUNT_DAILY A 
   LEFT JOIN  ML.SANDBOX_ML B
   ON A.WORK_ADDRESS_COUNTRY = B.COUNTRY
WHERE SNAP_DT=TIMESTAMP '2021-03-14 00:00:00.000000'
AND EMPLOYEE_ID > '444444'
GROUP BY b.region
```

Using a left join means that there can be countries without region, is that the case in your data model? Can a country be in many regions?

Comment: This is great. I did mess up my group by, I realized.
And no it, it's a many to one relationship. All countries have regions.

Answer (score 1):

The error you're getting is caused by your column naming as 'Region'.
When using AS use double quotation marks like: "Region".

```
SELECT A.WORK_ADDRESS_COUNTRY, COUNT(B.REGION) AS "Region"
```

Comment: Thank you! This runs successfully. I realized though the GROUP BY should be "Region" and not the country. When I change `GROUP BY A.WORK_ADDRESS_COUNTRY` to `GROUP BY B.REGION`, it throws this error: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that you want all countries in the second table, not the first.

```
SELECT S.COUNTRY, S.REGION, COUNT(E.EMPLOYEE_ID) AS Num_Employees
FROM COUNTRY, REGION FROM ML.SANDBOX_ML S LEFT JOIN
     ODS.ODS_HEADCOUNT_DAILY H
     ON H.WORK_ADDRESS_COUNTRY = S.COUNTRY AND
        SNAP_DT = DATE '2021-03-14' AND
        EMPLOYEE_ID > '444444'
GROUP BY S.COUNTRY, S.REGION;
```

Notes:

- I'm guessing you want a count of *employees*, not regions.
- The date arithmetic is simplified.
- If `EMPLOYEE_ID` is really a number drop the single quotes.